# Sending multiple .get() requests with Storyblok-nuxt

Tags: promise, get, axios, nuxt.js, storyblok

Can someone please guide me regarding sending multiple .get() requests with Storyblok-nuxt?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
context.app.$storyapi.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(
  context.app.$storyapi.spread((...responses) => {
  const responseOne = responses[0];
  const responseTwo = responses[1];

  console.log(responseOne, responseTwo, responesThree);
}));
```

Thanks.

Comment: This should print array of response values `context.app.$storyapi.all([requestOne, requestTwo]).then(values => { console.log(values) });`

Answer (score 0):

Since the JS client of Storyblok is using an `axios` wrapper you can do it like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const requestOne = context.app.$storyapi.get('cdn/stories' + 'health', { version: "published" })
const requestTwo = context.app.$storyapi.get('cdn/datasources', { version: "published" })
const requestThree = context.app.$storyapi.get('cdn/stories' + 'vue', { version: "published" })

axios.all([requestOne, requestTwo, requestThree]).then(axios.spread((...responses) => {
  const responseOne = responses[0]
  const responseTwo = responses[1]
  const responesThree = responses[2]
  // use/access the results 
})).catch(errors => {
  // react on errors.
})
```

Here is also a full tutorial on this: https://www.storyblok.com/tp/how-to-send-multiple-requests-using-axios